# Docker desktop tutorial failing - Invalid reference format

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker so Im trying out the tutorial and its failed at the first hurdle

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 / --name docker-tutorial2 docker101tutorial
```

This gives:

`docker: invalid reference format`.

Does anyone know the fix for this?  I have tried both / and , neither work

I am using a Windows 10 lapop

Comment: What is the `/` for? I assume you're running [this tutorial](https://www.docker.com/101-tutorial) ? If so the command is documented as `docker run -dp 80:80 docker/getting-started` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the slash character from the command, i.e.:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name docker-tutorial2 docker101tutorial
```